# HTML files are not recognised in Django project

Tags: python, html, django, visual-studio-code

I am learning Django,  everything was working fine but there was no syntax highlighting for django commands like `{% block body_block %} {% endblock %}` and so on...

So, i installed a vscode extensions `Django by Baptiste Darthenay` and `Django by Roberth Solis`, now syntax highlighting is working but HTML files are not recognised [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htxv6.png). There is no code completion, everything has to be typed word by word.

Disabling these extensions is working well, but then there is not syntax highlightling.

Please Help!!

Comment: There was no syntax highlighting because it's not a Python syntax. Your VS code was set to Python for its language setting, but Django uses a template engine called Django Template Engine to dynamically render data in templates.

Comment: You may refer to Django template plugin from VSCODE Market place for more details: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bibhasdn.django-html

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the extension you are using. You can refer to [here](https://github.com/vscode-django/vscode-django/issues/16) for more details.

Some people suggest add `"emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"}` in the settings.json file and it works, but it does not work on my side.

And you can switch the type of the file manually like this:

[image]

I am afraid it could not be solved recently as it has last for more than three years.